# How do i write to the beginning of the file? C++

Tags: c++, file

When I write to the beginning of the file,it always leaves the first line empty,and start writing from the second one.
How can I make it write from the first line,including the first one and on?
Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific. You may get better answers if you supply a code example showing what you're doing and what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are creating a new file or overwriting an existing file and afterwards the file starts with a blank line that you do not want?  If so, you are probably printing out a newline ("\n" or endl) at the beginning without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are outputting a newline character before the first line . Can you post some code that has the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that, if the file is not a new file, that you are not opening the file in 'append' mode.